# How to convert a list of high-dim tuples to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, embedding

I have a table from where I am getting my embedding data, it's contained in the `Embedding` column in the form of tuples having 3000 numbers. Now, I have to map the index of these embeddings to my dataset. I am using this code for the above:

```
p_x = [p_embedding[p_embedding['p_id'] == int(pid)]['Embedding'] for pid in p_mapping]
```

Edit: Adding sample data
Edit 2: Size is 300

`p_embedding` with tuple of size 300:

```
p_id   embedding
100    (0.11757241, -0.23792185, 0.30370793...)
101    (-0.1045902, 0.27551234, -0.15883833...)
102    (-0.0038427562, 0.091357835, -0.029324641...)
```

`p_mapping` with index mappings:

```
{'100': 0,
 '101': 1,
 '102': 2}
```

This gives me the list that I want containing the embeddings in the correct order, but it's still in the form of a tuple in one column. The first three rows are like this:

```
[Series([], Name: Embedding, dtype: object),
 2463    (-0.080065295, 0.085681394, 0.044956923, 0.078...
 Name: Embedding, dtype: object,
 2510    (0.19006088, 0.1552349, -0.028743511, -0.25197...
 Name: Embedding, dtype: object,
```

I want to split this tuple into separate columns of a dataframe, but when I do `pd.DataFrame` I just get a DF of 3000+ columns with all NAN values. Is there any reason behind this, do I have to change the index of the list?

Comment: better show example code with example data (as DataFrame) so we could copy and run it.

Comment: Sure, I have added sample code for both my tables

Comment: What is the numbers in the sample? 2643...? Is the sample a list of Series?

Comment: The number is actually the index of the row from the original `p_embedding` table. Right now, I'm looking into whether that might actually be the issue

Comment: UPDATE: I have solved the NAN issue by resetting the index in my new list, but I still can't split the tuples into a DF by `pd.DataFrame` or `.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'embedding': [[('123', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111'),
                            ('124', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111'),
                            ('125', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111')],
                           [],
                           [('123', '555', '333''456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111','123', '456', '111', '111')]]
                   })
final_rows = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row.embedding:  
        final_rows.append(row.p_id)
    for tup in row.embedding:
        new_row = [row.p_id]
        vals = list(tup)
        new_row.extend(vals)
        final_rows.append(new_row)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(final_rows)

df2.add_prefix('col_')
```

which gives:

```
col_0 col_1 col_2   col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7 col_8 col_9 col_10 col_11  \
0     A   123   456     111   111   123   456   111   111   123    456    111   
1     A   124   456     111   111   123   456   111   111   123    456    111   
2     A   125   456     111   111   123   456   111   111   123    456    111   
3     B  None  None    None  None  None  None  None  None  None   None   None   
4     C   123   555  333456   111   111   123   456   111   111    123    456   

  col_12 col_13  
0    111   None  
1    111   None  
2    111   None  
3   None   None  
4    111    111  
​
```

Comment: Yeah the iterrows is also a method. I actually found out that I needed to reformat my data with `literal_eval` before converting them to columns and then the regular `pd.DataFrame` worked perfectly. Really appreciate the solution though